# Nature (Monotonicity) of constant function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, monotone-functions

I am reading my course in stochastic process, and the professor defined in the beginning a constant function as an increasing and decreasing function in the same time. Can someone explain me why can't we just say that a constant function is a constant function and it's not monotonic ?
"Incresing" & "decreasing" are used by them in a strict or non strict sense ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your professor uses "increasing" and "decreasing" in the non-strict sense.  I would prefer to say "non-decreasing" and "non-increasing", but not everyone agrees.

Comment: So, can we say constant function is monotonic?